# add instructions to 8051 architecture

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, 8051, microprocessors

As you all know, most of the 8051 emulation/simulation softwares emulate 8051 Processor architecture.

Is there any such tool, which can append some extra Instructions into the 8051 Processor architecture and do some simulations and debug the codes.

OR,

if there is any method of doing this, you can suggest, without one tool?

Comment: What would be the point of emulating a processor which does not exist?

Comment: Presumably, any open-source implementation of an emulator, or HDL implementation for an FPGA/ASIC?  But I have to admit I don't remember off the top of my head if there are unused opcodes (or multi-byte instruction support) in that architecture - if so this should be simple, if not it will be tricky.  It is of course an architecture that has been extended (who would have ever thought we'd see 8051's with 256 megabytes of flash?) but that may be done more with special function registers than new opcodes.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - curiosity/learning most obviously, but then it *could* exist.  8051 derivatives find their way into lots of ASICs when people want to avoid license fees for an ARM or whatever core.  And anyone with around $50 or so can test an idea in an FPGA...

Comment: @ChrisStratton There appears to be exactly one undefined opcode (0xa5), which could be used as a leader for additional instructions.  8051 instructions are already variable-length, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know the [8051](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_MCS-51) architecture was still in use. It's from back in _my_ day.

Comment: Yep, there are industries and companies still using it, believe it or not.  I think some of the gigabit phys we use have 8051s that you download the code to make the chip work, I think that networking industry or players in it are still using 8051s.  So you might be reading this comment through one or many 8051 managed parts on yours or other computers.

Comment: as to the question, sure if you have an implementation you can change and there is room for more instructions (as I think was already mentioned) then sure you can add all you want.  And then you need to deal with tools ideally open source ones which you would need to change as well to match.  You can certainly do anything from change one little thing to completely make something new from scratch and anything in between.  Not sure I really understand your question though...do you want existing silicon to be able to add a new instruction without changing the silicon?

Comment: I assume this is for education purposes.  So, you could also go the other direction, and create your extra instructions using macros.  Same result from a conceptual point of view.

Comment: Tool recommendations are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: If you are wanting to extend the ISR with a complex instruction, you could also just make it a memory mapped co-processor. There is little performance penalty for doing this in the 8051 as it does not have a register file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution - which is not an easy one - is to get the code of an open source emulator like [this](http://www.moravia-microsystems.com/mcu-8051-ide/) and modify the processor model and the assembler to know your extra instructions.
Before you start you should study the processor architecture to know if your modifications are valid or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
@tonypdmtr It is not an educational purpose